# How to avoid tinting Icon with painterResource().It paints my vector in Black

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Okay so I have created my own .SVG vector icon and imported it as an XML in Android Studio. Now I'm trying to create an Icon using that same vector. However when I specify that vector in painterResource() it paints it in Black color. And my original SVG has multiple colors instead. Any raesons why is this happening?

```
Icon(
     painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_google_logo),
     contentDescription = "Google Button"
    )
```

When I add that icon this is what I see:
[image]

And this is how that icon should be actually displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The `Icon` applies a default tint based on `LocalContentColor.current` that is `Black` by default.

Use **`tint= Color.Unspecified`** to avoid it:

```
Icon(
     painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_google_logo),
     contentDescription = "Google Button",
     tint= Color.Unspecified
)
```

The other option is to use an **`Image`** instead of an `Icon`.

Answer (score 18):

Honestly, I don't think the accepted answer is the right thing to do. Icons tint automatically to the necessary contextual color.

If you want to show an icon without tinting, I'd suggest to use an Image instead:

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_google_logo),
    contentDescription = "Google Button"
)
```