# How can I change TopAppBar position in the jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to set the "Account" text to the center of TopAppBar and add an icon to the right of TopAppBar, how can I do it?

[image]

```
 Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.account),
                        style = AppFont.PoppinsTypography.subtitle1
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_left),
                        contentDescription = "back", tint = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE
                    )
                }, actions = {
                    viewModel.navigateUp()
                }, backgroundColor = AppColor.neutralColor.DOCTOR
            )
        },
    )
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497414/how-to-align-title-at-layout-center-in-topappbar/67499847#67499847

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To align the title text to the center of `TopAppbar`,

### Update

#### Using Material 3

CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
title = {
Text(
text = stringResource(R.string.account),
style = AppFont.PoppinsTypography.subtitle1
)
},
)

And `actions` attribute should have the compoosables to add at the end. Use that to add an icon to the right of `TopAppBar`.

Example,

```
actions = {
    IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ShoppingCart,
            contentDescription = "cart",
        )
     }
 },
```

---

#### The old answer, using Material 2

Change `title` to this,

```
title = {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(R.string.account),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        style = AppFont.PoppinsTypography.subtitle1
    )
},
```

Comment: My problem is solved but when I use SVG for icons, the icon is black and with color, while the icon is colered.                                 painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_left)

Comment: I found the solution for changing the icon SVG color :       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234441/painterresource-paints-my-vector-in-black

Comment: did that really work? because I don't think align would actually work here. That is what I tried before implementing a custom layout as I've posted below. Can you post an image?

Comment: @MARSK,  It is not at the exact center of the app bar if that is the expectation. This centers within the text label space, which seems to be good enough for me. We have to use a custom layout for exact center.

Comment: Even if it was close to the center, maybe I'd consider it (no I won't), but it is almost at the edge in my case.

Comment: Hope this helps someone, the textAlign only worked for me when I added Modifier.weight(1f)

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement a custom layout

```
@Composable
fun TopBar() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            Layout(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.1f), //Fills one-tenth of the screen
                content = {
                    Text("Account")

                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "back",
                        tint = Color.Blue,
                    )
                }
            ) { measurables, constraints ->

                val title = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
                val navigationIcon = measurables[1].measure(constraints)

                layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {

                    title.place(
                        (constraints.maxWidth - title.width) / 2, //Midway
                        constraints.maxHeight / 2 // Usually Texts acquire maxHeight so we did not need t subtract
                    )

                    navigationIcon.place(
                        (constraints.maxWidth - 1.5 * navigationIcon.width).roundToInt(), //1.5 to add a bit of extra padding from the edge
                        (constraints.maxHeight - navigationIcon.height) / 2
                    )

                }
            }
        },
    ) {

    }
}
```