# Icon color is not changing even after changing the fill color in xml file

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

[image]

This is the code of like icon svg and I have changed the color to pink from black, but when I try to display the icon using compose it's appearing as black only as u can see down

[image]

The compose code is

```
Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.liked), contentDescription =null )
```

Comment: try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234441/how-to-avoid-tinting-icon-with-painterresource-it-paints-my-vector-in-black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.liked), contentDescription = null, 
    tint = Color(0xFFE91E63))
```

Comment: What if the vector has different paths and each path needs to define different color?